# BootstrapValidator conditional validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [BootstrapValidator](http://www.bootstrapvalidator.com) and I have some text fields and a radio button with 2 options, I need to validate a text field only if the radiobutton option 2 is selected, how can I obtain it?

This is the form:

```
<form action="/it/Account/SignUp" class="form-horizontal" id="signup_form" method="post" role="form">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
<label>Company</label>
<input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" id="company">
<input type="radio" name="usertype" value="0"><label>Private</label>
<input type="radio" name="usertype" value="1"><label>Company</label>

</form>
```

This is the JavaScript for BootstrapValidator:

```
$('#signup_form').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    live: 'disabled',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        name: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'required'
                },
            }                
        },
        company: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'required'
                },
            }                
        },
    }
}
```

I need only to validate the "company" field only if the radio value of 'usertype' is equal to 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an example of what you have tried so far, and the issues you encountered? You're more likely to receive a helpful response from the community if you can demonstrate that you attempted to solve the problem before posting.

Comment: i inserted a code sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the `callback` validation option

https://formvalidation.io/guide/validators/callback

you can create a custom function for validation, return a boolean of true or false, you should then do your checks on the fieldValue depending on if the radio button is checked

Comment: Could you explain it little bit? I am not getting from the example at: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/callback/

Comment: how can he run existing validators within the callback function?

Comment: This link is not working. I think this will give you an idea http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/callback/